# Automapper Entity Framework Core Include Filter Mapping Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

After a bit of research I am aware you cannot have an include filter on an entity framework core clause. My collection entity `Skill` has a soft delete flag which I need to filter out from the collection sat inside of `SkillGroup`. I have used a select to create the list I need however the automapper fails as the types are different. I could loop through this and build it in the way automapper want's but I figure there must be a more elegant solution or something I am missing.

```
public List<SkillGroupModel> GetAllSkillGroupSkills()
    {
        var skillGroups = _context.SkillGroups.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)
                                            .Select(c => new
                                            {
                                                c,
                                                Skills = c.Skills.Where(i => !i.IsDeleted)
                                            }).AsEnumerable();

        List<SkillGroupModel> rtn = _mapper.Map<List<SkillGroupModel>>(skillGroups);

        //List<SkillGroupModel> rtn = _mapper.Map<List<SkillGroupModel>>(_context.SkillGroups.Include(x => x.Skills.Where(b => !b.IsDeleted).Where(x => !x.IsDeleted));

        return rtn;
    }
```

Edit --
As per suggested in the comments changed profile to `MapFrom`:

```
public class SkillProfile : Profile
{
    public SkillProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Skill, SkillModel>()
            .ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<SkillGroup, SkillGroupModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Skills, conf => conf.MapFrom(source => source.Skills.Where(i => !i.IsDeleted)))
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

And then added `ProjectTo` to my clause:

```
public List<SkillGroupModel> GetAllSkillGroupSkills()
{
    var ef = _context.SkillGroups.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).Include(x => x.Skills).ProjectTo<SkillGroupModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
    List <SkillGroupModel> rtn = _mapper.Map<List<SkillGroupModel>>(ef);

    return rtn;
 }
```

Comment: You can use `ProjectTo` and `MapFrom(source => source.Skills.Where(i => !i.IsDeleted))`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu This will do the filtering for the soft deleted flags at the mapping rather than at the EF call though? It works for me now because I have such a small dataset, but say you had thousands of soft deleted rows how would you handle it then?

Comment: @Progman I have read this article already, is the only solution really to use 3rd party plugins?

Comment: @sm.th Do you want to filter at the database/EF level or at the automapper level?

Comment: @Progman I guess I need the filter to be applied at the data call before the mapping occurs because the soft delete flag could be applied to a lot of members. Sorry if my question was not clear on that.

Comment: `ProjectTo` gets interpreted by EF. http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: Have edited the question with your suggestion. This seems to work. If I pass my dependency injected mapper configuration down to the `ProjectTo` this should tell EF to only query those with that profile?

Comment: You don't need the `Include` with `ProjectTo`. But really, do spend some time with the docs and some working examples. The more you understand about it, the better you'll be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you using `ProjectTo` extension method, don't need to use
   `Include`. because query and mapping execute in `DataBase`.
2. You can map `SkillGroups` to `List<SkillGroupModel>` and don't need
   to map to `SkillGroupModel` then `List<SkillGroupModel>`

```cs
public List<SkillGroupModel> GetAllSkillGroupSkills()
{
    return _context.SkillGroups.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)
                .ProjectTo<List<SkillGroupModel>>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToList();
}
```

Comment: `ProjectTo<SkillGroupModel>`